# Deploying a working Java project to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a Java web project done by another team, that is hosted on a Tomcat. I am asked to do some modification in the project.

Modifying JSP- and HTML-files is fine, but when it comes to modifying an existing Java-file, I need to import the full project to some IDE like Eclipse. How can I import the full project?

Comment: Can you get the eclipse project  from the other team? Do you have te source code as eclipse project?

Comment: It would be easier if you could get the entire eclipse project.

Comment: With a `.project`file?

Comment: do u have war file of that project. Then you can import war file in IDE of eclipse.

Comment: Do you have access to source control management`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps below to import an existing JAVA project:

1. Copy the java project to your workspace (ex. C:/workspace)
2. Go to Eclipse IDE
3. Navigate to File->New->Java Project
4. A dialog box will display. Enter the exact name (case-sensitive) to the Project Name field.
5. The Location field value should be where the project is currently located (ex. C:/workspace/MyProject)
6. Click Finish.
7. The project should now be displayed in the Package Explorer panel (or Project Explorer).

Note: If the project is Web, you should choose File->New->Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: now when i run any file server starts then eclipse closed

Answer (score 0):

Check with the other team what IDE they use. Usually the project might also contain IDE files (.project & .classpath) for Eclipse given you have access to the source code.

If not, create a new Project (using the Java EE edition) and look at the directory structure for some sample projects. You should then be able to create the structure in your new project accordingly.